# nginx - return http 410 code for every path

Tags: nginx

I'm trying to configure nginx to return a http 410 ("Resource Gone") code for ***any*** path under /

My config is below.

With this config, if I request /410test, I get a standard nginx 404 Not Found page, and a response status code of 404.  So I'm having trouble even getting a response of 410 for one specific path, much less, all paths.

```
user www-data;
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;
include /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/*.conf;

events {
    worker_connections 768;
    # multi_accept on;
}

http {
    server {
        location /410test {
                return 410 "this is my 410 test page";
        }

    }


    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    tcp_nodelay on;
    keepalive_timeout 65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;

    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    gzip on;

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing the `listen` directive from the `server` block in your config. You are getting 404s from your sites defined under `conf.d` & `sites-enabled`.

Answer (score 0):

Put `return` directly in the `server` context:

```
http {
    server {
        return 410 "this is my 410 test page";
    }
}
```

Why it doesn't work with your config, is maybe because you're trying to access `/410test/` (with trailing slash) which doesn't match your defined `location`.